# C/C++ Query EDID at boot time

Tags: c, android, c++, edid, ioctl

I'm looking for a way to query EDID data at boot time on my Android system.

I think I can use `ioctl` calls and I see that the frame buffers are at `/sys/class/graphics/fb*`. But currently I'm just getting garbage output.

Here is the command I'm currently using which works great with frame buffers at `/dev/graphics/fb*`:

```
int fb0_handle = open("/dev/graphics/fb0\0", O_RDONLY);
ioctl(fb0_handle, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo0);
```

But I want to be able to use EDID data instead. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Any suggestions would be nice, I was thinking perhaps some `H2C*` commands might be suitable but I haven't found anything solid yet.